# fsck:error 2 (no such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext2 for /dev/sda2

Tags: fsck

[image: this is a fsck error]
/dev/sda2: warning:filesystem still has errors
fsck exited with status code 12
The root filesystem on /dev/sda2 requires a manual fsck

```
Enter help for a list of built-in commands. 
(initramfs) fsck
fsck from util-linux 2.34
(initramfs) fsck /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.34
[164.609826] blk_update_request:I/O error, dev sda, sector 500117376 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[164.613609] blk_update_request:I/O error, dev sda, sector 500117376 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[164.615797] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 62383344, async page read

fsck:error 2 (no such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext2 for /dev/sda2
```

Comment: I'd seriously consider checking the cables. The lines at the very top of the screen are typical of faulty connections or not enough power to the disk. Doesn't mean this is the cause but it's worth checking

Answer (score 1):

Looks bad. Hope you have some nightly backups available.

What happened to this system? It wasn't just "powerfail during writes", it was something more serious. Maybe you physically picked up the host while it was writing? Winchester drives don't respond well to jostling while active. The ten-second timeouts bode ill.

If sda2 corresponds to writable blocks, then fsck *will* fix it and the FS will eventually check clean. But it appears that some blocks are unwritable :-(

Use [ddrescue](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ddrescue),
which patiently waits through more error retries than
[dd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dd), to copy blocks out to new media, and fsck that.
Or just abandon the disk and discard it,
if you have nightly backups or if there's little of value on it.
In any event the disk is toast,
it's not a good candidate for a fresh install.

If you really really want to keep using that media,
you'll have to spend a lot of time
writing, re-writing, reading, and re-reading blocks
to convince yourself they are usable,
and carefully map out the bad sections.
This assumes the destructive process which
caused bad blocks in the first place is now gone and won't recur,
which seems a pretty shaky assumption at present.

Comment: Is my laptop and data safe?

Comment: Use `ddrescue` rather than `dd`

Comment: I am going to install Ubuntu again. I hope it will work.

Comment: The messages suggest the `sda` disk may be failing. The `fsck` command is just a wrapper that calls a filesystem-specific filesystem checker, e.g. `/sbin/fsck.ext2` for `ext2`-type filesystems. Apparently that was not available within the initramfs file, and since the wrapper's attempts to detect the filesystem type returned read errors, the type identification might not have been correct in the first place. Even if the disk is not completely dead, it might be unreliable in the future. I'd recommend replacing it; ideally with a SSD, since a SSD is insensitive to physical jostling unlike a HDD.

Comment: @user586542 "_Is my laptop and data safe?_" - at this point I'd have to say "no, it's not"